Stochastic exponential and Girsanov
Let's say I have an instrument $V$ with payoff at maturity: $P(S_T)$ (for example $1_{S > K}$) that I want to price under stochastic rates: $dr_t = \mu dt + \theta_t dW_t$, with $W_t$ a Brownian motion correlated to the brownian motion driving the stock price $S$.
Then by introducing: $D(t, T) = e^{\int_t^T r_s ds}$, I now that under the $\mathbb{Q}_D$ measure the process $t \mapsto \frac{V_t}{D(0, t)}$ is a martingale, hence:
$$\frac{V_t}{D(0, t)} = E^{\mathbb{Q}_D}[\frac{V_T}{D(0, T)} | F_t] \implies V_t = E^{\mathbb{Q}_D}[e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} \times P(S_T) | F_t] = E^M[e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} \times P(S_T) \times \frac{d\mathbb{Q}_D}{dM}| F_t]$$
Where $M$ is a measure such that: $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_D}{dM} = D(t, T)$ so that at the end I am left wit the simple expectation: $E^M[P(S_T) | F_t]$.
Though in order to be able to calculate that expectation I need to be able to see what is the dynamic of: $t \mapsto  W^{M}_t$ under the measure $M$.  To do so we normally used the Girsanov theorem and express: $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_D}{dM}$ as a stochastic exponential martingale. Though how can I express $D(t, T)$ as a stochastic exponential martingale? I tried developping but couldn't arrive to desired form.
I also thought about using the risk neutral measure but I don't see how it could work. Since we are in a stochastic rates environment then considering that there is a constant risk free rate $r$ such that $B(t) = e^{r \cdot t}$ wouldn't make any sense since my rates are stochastic and hence no risk free constant rate exist. So I can't use the risk neutral measure that says: $t \mapsto \frac{V_t}{B(t)}$ is a martingale since $B(t)$ can't be defined since there's no constant risk-free rate.
My question is then two fold:

How can you we find a way to put: $D(t, T)$ in a stochastic integral form so that I can use Girsanov to change the dynamic of my brownian motion?

How can the risk-neutral measure be defined in that case? Because I need initially a dynamic for my brownian motion, and I don't even know it under $\mathbb{Q}_D$.


